# Set Facebook Profile to Not Appear In Friends Lists

Tags: facebook

If you want your Facebook profile to not show up in the friend's lists of your friends, can you set it up to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the display of your friends on your profile.

Your friends will still see your profile, but not your list of friends.

The general public when looking at your public profile will not see your friends.
The general public when looking at one of your friends' profiles that does not hide their friends' list, will see that you are friends with that person.

There are no settings in Facebook that you can set, to change that behavior. Your only setting is whether or not you want people, who are viewing your profile, to see your friends' list.